# Gas combi boiler - left running constantly in cold weather

Tags: central-heating, boiler

I've a gas combi-boiler that is generally working fine, but we're getting some seriously cold weather here at the minute (for us anyway) and I've had the odd problem with the boiler starting up when it has got very cold.

We're going to be away for a few days over Christmas, and I'm thinking about just leaving the boiler running constantly while we're away (don't want a start up to fail and my house to freeze).  Does anybody think that it's a problem to run the boiler constantly like this?

Comment: Has the system got a "frost" setting?

Comment: It does, but the problems have come from the flue getting very cold and causing some problems with the condensate. (we've a relatively long horizontal run of flue in our kitchen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by the by, I left the boiler running happily for a week with the thermostat turned down - no problems.  Just hoping for some warmer weather now...

Answer (score 1):

If your condensate pipe may get frozen, see if you can disconnect the pipe and run the condensate into a backet.  Frozen condensate pipe have been a big problem with the recent weather.